# Python raw_input to extract from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to implement a solution where I call the displayPerson() that takes the user input for an id number and will print the information for the user. I should note that I'm downloading a csv file from the internet that contains data in this format:

id, name , birthday
 
1, Jack Sparrow, 09/20/2000

My goal is to get a number from the user which will look up and display the ID. I want the prompt to continue to show up and ask the user for a number until they enter a negative number or 0 to exit.

```
    loop= True
    while loop== True:
        prompt = int(raw_input(" Enter ID of person you would like to search for: "))
        break

    if prompt >0:

        displayPerson(prompt,persons)


    else:
        print("Terminated.")
```

As it stands now, I am able to get the output correct if the user enters a positive digit between 1-100 but the program stops when I would like it to ask the user for another number and I can't fathom how to work this so that it will give the user a message to enter another number less than 101 (instead of giving me a KeyError), display the data, and then ask for another number. If the user enters a zero it gives the "Terminated" message and then stops but I'm finding it hard to do anything else.

Here is the displayPerson() function for reference:

```
def displayPerson(id, personDataDictionary):
    """

    :param id:
    :param personDataDictionary: Look at displayPerson in __name__ function. But I thought bday was pieces[2].
    :return:
    """
    print("id = {}, name = {}, birthday = {}".format(id, personDataDictionary[id][0],
                                                     personDataDictionary[id][1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the top `while` loop?

Comment: the top while loop was my attempt to get the prompt to run continuously after the user was able to display the results of one valid number. I realize this was defeated by "break" but that was my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
while True:
    prompt = int(raw_input(" Enter ID of person you would like to search for: "))

    if prompt > 100:
        print("Please try again")
        continue 
    elif prompt < 1: 
        displayPerson(prompt,persons)
    else:
        break

print("Terminated.")
```

**Explanation**

You enter the loop and get an ID from the user.

If `prompt > 0`: display the person
Otherwise, break out of the loop and print "Terminated".

Comment: Is there a way to use this and set another condition for the input to be < 101? If it is not there will be a key error so I need to ask them again to enter ID, but not terminate.

Comment: Edited solution. I highly suggest going back to the books and/or some online code teacher platform.